# Is the expected value a valid decision-making method in a very short term?

Tags: expected-value, decision-theory

This might be related to game theory more than statistics, but I decided to ask this question here.

Let's assume you're offered a lottery. There are a hundred balls in a bowl: 99 white balls and one red ball. You are allowed to pick one ball at random (obviously without seeing what color it is). If the ball you picked is red, you win \$100. However, if you pick a white ball, you lose \$1. The expected value of the lottery is .99* (-\$1) + .01 * \$100 = \$.01. This suggests that you should play the lottery, since it allows you to win one cent on average.

The expected value in this case means that if you play the lottery an infinite amount of times, you'll average a gain of one cent per game. However, what if you're only allowed to play the lottery once or twice or three times? Is the expected value still a viable decision-making device in such a scenario?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'viable'? Some people might be happy to choose to play on the basis of expectation (indeed, real people often choose to play lotteries, which have negative expectation). Other people may be more risk averse. Both are viable in some sense (such as in the sense that different utilities for different people may be reasonable).

Comment: @Glen_b by 'viable' I mean one that allows you to make the right decision according to the information you have. The commonly accepted rule is that if the EV is positive, you should play the game. The example I've given has positive EV, but the probability of winning is very low compared to the probability of losing. If you were allowed to play the lottery indefinitely, it wouldn't be bad, since you could lose 100 times in a row, win once and still break even. My question is, however, how does EV fare as a decision-making device if the implicit condition of 'infiniteness' is not fulfilled?

Comment: "Commonly accepted" where? To use EV as a principle under *all* circumstances would be to state that risk aversion was somehow a mistake. What makes a decision 'right' is if it respects the individual's own preferences relating to risk and money. If losing one dollar means I can't make my rent (which I have to pay today), I'd be insane to play. But my neighbor has a few hundred dollars to spare, and losing a dollar will mean almost nothing to her, so maximizing expectation would make much more sense in her case, were she so inclined.

Comment: @Glen_b: Suppose the winnings are 100 & -1 units of utility rather than $.

Comment: @Scortchi I have no particular problem discussing expected utility, but that's a quite different question to the one posted (which specifically focuses on risk). If a person were to accept the notion of utility as is (some people reject it for various reasons, some of which carry some force, I think), that person might well argue that almost by definition expected utility is what one should seek to maximize, since it already incorporates attitudes to risk (in my rent example, it would already include my large negative utility to losing $1 if it would cause me to miss paying my rent on time).